# Xcode 13.4.1 User defined runtime attribute string "0" saved as ""

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, xcode13

*this only started after upgrading to Xcode 13.4.1*

I have a User defined runtime attribute named `numberString` that has values 0-9 defined as string. The custom view then sets them to a label text property. So strings from interface builder all the way to the label.

```
@IBInspectable
open var numberString = "2" {
    didSet {
        label.text = numberString
    }
}
```

With Xcode 13.4.1 the `numberString` property contains an empty string if the property is defined as `0`.

I check the xml source of that xib and it does contain `"0"`:

```
<userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
    <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="numberString" value="0"/>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
```

I also found that if I define any other property it works correctly, even if I just define this property twice:

```
<userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
    <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="numberString" value="0"/>
    <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="numberString" value="0"/>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
```

This didn't happen with older Xcode versions but for some reason I can't reproduce it in a new storyboard project.

Comment: *"I can't reproduce it in a new storyboard project"* ... it's possible there is some other error / corruption in the xib file. If you can't reproduce it, it's going to be ***very*** difficult to come up with any other answer.

Comment: Have you found any solution for that?

Comment: @jigs nope, I defined it twice and that way it works, still no idea why it stopped working